# How can I read response content (that is JSON) from Django middleware so I can convert it to HTML?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

From my django view I am returning a serialized JSON as below:

```
def features(request):
    features = db_service.fetch_all_features()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', features)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

I have registered a middleware, where I want to fetch this JSON and convert it into HTML

```
class ReturnResponseAsHTML:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after

        #return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')

        return response
```

Once I have access to the response object, how may I fetch the JSON from it so I may convert it to HTML

Answer (score -1):

```
response.getvalue()
```

where response is an instance of django.http.HttpResponse